# is there some module just like PAM in python?

Tags: python, linux, pam

I wanna do a auth certification on the base of linux account (just like PAM), and which should be realized by python. or should I write the encrypt algorithm of linux, I mean does each distribution own the same encrypt method?

Answer (score 1):

I do find a module called pam, which is realized by ctype (call PAM of your system).

snippet:

```
import pam

if pam.authenticate('username','password'):
    print 'authentication correct'
else:
    print 'authentication incorrect'
```